# Finding change in shared object through bash

Tags: shell-script, files, package-management

Here's my case- I have a package named say `foo-1.2.3`. I want to know which package it installs. So, I install it in a `fakeroot` approach and make a list of all files it install in a file called `FILES`

Suppose I want to upgrade it to `foo-1.2.4`. In the same way, I created the `FILES` file for it. I know that if the name of the shared library changes, all the packages dynamically linked to it needs to be re-compiled. So I want to write a bash script which will notify me.

For example, say the old `FILES` contains-

```
/usr/lib/libfoo.so.1
/usr/lib/libfooabc.so.1
/usr/lib/something.so.1
/usr/share/doc/foo-1.2.3/whatever
```

And let's say the new `FILES` contains-

```
/usr/lib/libfoo.so.2
/usr/lib/libfooabc.so.2
/usr/lib/something.so.1
/usr/share/doc/foo-1.2.4/whatever
```

I want the script to notify me that, `/usr/lib/libfoo.so.1` and `/usr/lib/libfooabc.so.1` have changed.

I tried this

```
grep -F -x -f old new|grep -E *\.so\.*
```

But it doesn't work as expected when the file `old` is-

```
/usr/lib/libfooabc.so.1
/usr/lib/libfoo.so.1
/usr/lib/libfoo.so.2
/usr/lib/something.so.1
/usr/share/doc/foo-1.2.3/whatever
```

And `new` is-

```
/usr/lib/libfoo.so.2
/usr/lib/libfoo.so.3
/usr/lib/libfooabc.so.2
/usr/lib/something.so.1
/usr/share/doc/foo-1.2.4/whatever
```

The output is-

```
/usr/lib/libfoo.so.2
/usr/lib/something.so.1
```

The desired output is-

```
/usr/lib/libfooabc.so.1
/usr/lib/libfoo.so.1
```

Comment: @StephenKitt See the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with two options using diff that should work for you.

#### Using diff -u and sed:

```
diff -u old new | sed  -n 's/^-\(.*\.so\..*\)/\1/p'
/usr/lib/libfoo.so.1
/usr/lib/libfooabc.so.1
```

- That command outputs the full diff between the two files, and we use
  sed to filter out only the changes from the 'old' file (indicated by
  a leading -), and further filter on the diff containing `.so.`. To
  strip out the - from the diff output we use a backreference to print
  everything but that.

#### Using diff output formatting and grep

Two variants on the same thing; the second one is shorter, they both behave identically to each other and the previous example.

```
diff --old-line-format='%L' --unchanged-line-format= --new-line-format= old new | grep '\.so\.'
```

or slightly better:

```
diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-line-format=  old new | grep '\.so\.'
```

You may be able to get diff to do the job entirely by itself - it does have regex filtering (-I ignore flag), but it behaves oddly when you need to invert the regex. I've never had much luck with it.